# File is not getting found by the js in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles

I am trying to use the example from the following: https://bl.ocks.org/anilnairxyz/a51393d7c51342abe8d4e3f4cbab7ae1

I have modified the example with simple tweaks to get it landed in the Django framework. Here is the template code:
**temp.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'test/cschart.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demobox">
        <div id="csbox">
            <div id="option">
                <input id="oneM" name="1M" type="button" value="1M"/>
                <input id="threeM" name="3M" type="button" value="3M" />
                <input id="sixM" name="6M" type="button" value="6M" />
                <input id="oneY" name="1Y" type="button" value="1Y" />
                <input id="twoY" name="2Y" type="button" value="2Y" />
                <input id="fourY" name="4Y" type="button" value="4Y" />
            </div>
            <div id="infobar">
                <div id="infodate" class="infohead"></div>
                <div id="infoopen" class="infobox"></div>
                <div id="infohigh" class="infobox"></div>
                <div id="infolow" class="infobox"></div>
                <div id="infoclose" class="infobox"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="chart1"></div>
        </div> <!-- csbox -->
    </div> <!-- demobox -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'test/cschart.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'test/csbars.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'test/csheader.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'test/csdataprep.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'test/csmain.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def temp(request):
    return render(request, 'tt/temp.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tt/', views.show),
    path('pie/', views.pie),
    path('dd3/', views.testingD3),
path('fera/', views.fera),
path('line/', views.lined3),
path('temp/', views.temp),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I have kept the complete js and css in the `static/test` folder and have access the js and css successfully. But Am not able to locate the stockdata.csv file. Have a look at the files directory:
[image: directory structure]

Here is the problem in console log:
[image: output error image]

Please help me get to the file. I even tried to create a folder named `temp` and has placed the `csv` file inside it but failed, as still I got the same error.

The js file giving issues is here:

```
var parseDate    = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var TPeriod      = "3M";
var TDays        = {"1M":21, "3M":63, "6M":126, "1Y":252, "2Y":504, "4Y":1008 };
var TIntervals   = {"1M":"day", "3M":"day", "6M":"day", "1Y":"week", "2Y":"week", "4Y":"month" };
var TFormat      = {"day":"%d %b '%y", "week":"%d %b '%y", "month":"%b '%y" };
var genRaw, genData;

(function() {
    d3.csv("stockdata.csv", genType, function(data) {
      genRaw         = data;
      mainjs();
    }); 
}());

function toSlice(data) { return data.slice(-TDays[TPeriod]); }

function mainjs() {
  var toPress    = function() { genData = (TIntervals[TPeriod]!="day")?dataCompress(toSlice(genRaw), TIntervals[TPeriod]):toSlice(genRaw); };
  toPress(); displayAll();
  d3.select("#oneM").on("click",   function(){ TPeriod  = "1M"; toPress(); displayAll(); });
  d3.select("#threeM").on("click", function(){ TPeriod  = "3M"; toPress(); displayAll(); });
  d3.select("#sixM").on("click",   function(){ TPeriod  = "6M"; toPress(); displayAll(); });
  d3.select("#oneY").on("click",   function(){ TPeriod  = "1Y"; toPress(); displayAll(); });
  d3.select("#twoY").on("click",   function(){ TPeriod  = "2Y"; toPress(); displayAll(); });
  d3.select("#fourY").on("click",  function(){ TPeriod  = "4Y"; toPress(); displayAll(); });
}

function displayAll() {
    changeClass();
    displayCS();
    displayGen(genData.length-1);
}

function changeClass() {
    if (TPeriod =="1M") {
        d3.select("#oneM").classed("active", true);
        d3.select("#threeM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#sixM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#oneY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#twoY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#fourY").classed("active", false);
    } else if (TPeriod =="6M") {
        d3.select("#oneM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#threeM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#sixM").classed("active", true);
        d3.select("#oneY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#twoY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#fourY").classed("active", false);
    } else if (TPeriod =="1Y") {
        d3.select("#oneM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#threeM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#sixM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#oneY").classed("active", true);
        d3.select("#twoY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#fourY").classed("active", false);
    } else if (TPeriod =="2Y") {
        d3.select("#oneM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#threeM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#sixM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#oneY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#twoY").classed("active", true);
        d3.select("#fourY").classed("active", false);
    } else if (TPeriod =="4Y") {
        d3.select("#oneM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#threeM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#sixM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#oneY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#twoY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#fourY").classed("active", true);
    } else {
        d3.select("#oneM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#threeM").classed("active", true);
        d3.select("#sixM").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#oneY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#twoY").classed("active", false);
        d3.select("#fourY").classed("active", false);
    }
}

function displayCS() {
    var chart       = cschart().Bheight(460);
    d3.select("#chart1").call(chart);
    var chart       = barchart().mname("volume").margin(320).MValue("TURNOVER");
    d3.select("#chart1").datum(genData).call(chart);
    var chart       = barchart().mname("sigma").margin(400).MValue("VOLATILITY");
    d3.select("#chart1").datum(genData).call(chart);
    hoverAll();
}

function hoverAll() {
    d3.select("#chart1").select(".bands").selectAll("rect")
          .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
              d3.select(this).classed("hoved", true);
              d3.select(".stick"+i).classed("hoved", true);
              d3.select(".candle"+i).classed("hoved", true);
              d3.select(".volume"+i).classed("hoved", true);
              d3.select(".sigma"+i).classed("hoved", true);
              displayGen(i);
          })                  
          .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
              d3.select(this).classed("hoved", false);
              d3.select(".stick"+i).classed("hoved", false);
              d3.select(".candle"+i).classed("hoved", false);
              d3.select(".volume"+i).classed("hoved", false);
              d3.select(".sigma"+i).classed("hoved", false);
              displayGen(genData.length-1);
          });
}

function displayGen(mark) {
    var header      = csheader();
    d3.select("#infobar").datum(genData.slice(mark)[0]).call(header);
}
```

Have a look at my **setting.py** file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print("Base URL is \n:    ",BASE_DIR)

SECRET_KEY = '#7xfs=i@n*!frchr_e)vaw!r=1c2fy-zu%070gdy6fe_=h_du_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']    


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'demod3',
    'django_nvd3',
    'djangobower',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
print("Statcic URL is :    \n:  ", STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this piece:

```
(function() {
    d3.csv("stockdata.csv", genType, function(data) {
      genRaw         = data;
      mainjs();
    }); 
}());
```

change to:

```
(function() {
    d3.csv("/static/test/stockdata.csv", genType, function(data) {
      genRaw         = data;
      mainjs();
    }); 
}());
```

The issue is that django and the js file cannot share data unless you render the js using django.

Not sure if this would work in this case, but you could take that specific function out and embed it into your template file:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var parseDate    = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    var TPeriod      = "3M";
    var TDays        = {"1M":21, "3M":63, "6M":126, "1Y":252, "2Y":504, "4Y":1008 };
    var TIntervals   = {"1M":"day", "3M":"day", "6M":"day", "1Y":"week", "2Y":"week", "4Y":"month" };
    var TFormat      = {"day":"%d %b '%y", "week":"%d %b '%y", "month":"%b '%y" };
    var genRaw, genData;

    (function() {
        d3.csv("{% static 'test/stockdata.csv' %}", genType, function(data) {
          genRaw         = data;
          mainjs();
        }); 
    }());
</script>
```

Not sure how that will affect the rest of the script

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. Just one query. If I replace the line `d3.csv("/static/test/stockdata.csv", genType, function(data)` like this `d3.csv("{5 static 'test/stockdata.csv' %}", genType, function(data)` will they be same?

Comment: The issue is that django will not see it as template code and will therefore never process the variable. you could generate the js using django, but you are going to be coding around aproblem instead of solving it

Comment: You could take that one specific function out and embed it into your template and that would work...

Comment: Sir I tried changing the `js` code in the file but the issue is still the same.

Comment: same error as before? also, keep in mind that the browser caches js - so it may not have picked up your change - add a `?12345` afeter the file name in the `<script src="{% static 'test/csmain.js?12345' %}"></script>`